# Display View in New Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have developed an ASP.NET MVC application that will run several prescreen functions based on user input.

The plan is to call this new mvc app from an existing HTML/JavaScript application. I would like to display the controllers's view in a new browser window outside of the calling application.

My AJAX call will look something like this

```
$.support.cors = true;

$.ajax( {
    url: "http://mvc_url/prescreen",
    data: jsonObject,
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    dataType: 'html',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    timeout: 60000,
    //dataType: "json",
    success: function ( msg )
    {
        ...on success msg = html rendered from view...
    },
    error: function ( XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown )
    {
        ...error handling...
    }
} );
```

I've tested this and on success msg does contain the fully rendered HTML from the view. My question is how do I open a new window using the rendered HTML?.

I've tried the following:

```
var newWindow = window.open( "", "", "" );
newWindow.document.write( msg );
```

and that seems to work. sort of. The new window opens and the html is displayed, but then my style sheets and included javascript files, for the view, are missing. So if using the above window.open code is correct, then how do I bring down the necessary stylesheets and javascript files?

> **EDIT**

Utilizing the suggestion provided by AndyJ, I've modified my view to include relative paths based on my base application. Here is the returned mark up from my MVC

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Offer</title>

    <link href="../css/site.css", type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container body-content">

    ... Page Content ...

    <script src="/baseapp/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/baseapp/js/someInclude.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        InitializeForm();
    </script>
```

the InitializeForm method is defined within the someInclude.js.

Based on the above and assuming the files are locates in the paths, everything should link up, correct? So what else might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Just a guess, if you are returning the HTML in the AJAX request you should probably add the CSS and JS references to that. You are not really returning a view that would normally have a layout attached.

Comment: @AndyJ good point. I hadn't really thought about that. I'll give that a try. Would you mind adding it as an answer? I want to be able to give you proper credit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are returning raw HTML in the AJAX request you will probably need to add the CSS and JS references there. You are not really returning a view that would normally have a layout that includes the references.

Comment: thank you. So far my styles sheets are linking correctly. However, I'm running into an issue getting both the jquery library and a javascript file to link. I've added, to my view, paths relative to my css, jquery, and include file from my base application. I wonder if I need use jquery to add my include to the head after I return from my ajax call.

Comment: You can try it. Is the jquery creating the HTML for you or is that coming from the server?

Comment: The HTML is being returned from the server. I simply open a new window and write the returned data to the new window's document object

Comment: Then I would just add the js and css reference to the server code and you should be fine. Unless you don't have access to that code, you will need to use jQuery to add it in.

Comment: My apologies, but I am getting nowhere with this. My css file is being attached very nicely and that link is in my view. However, I cannot get jquery to link. I am even using the fully qualified URL to Google's hosted API. I am at a serious loss here

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the help provided by Andy J (Thank you), I also found that when the response was rendered in the new window, the JQuery library was loading **AFTER** my initialization script. To circumvent this, I simply added my event handlers to the inline attributes of the controls.

This may be a work around, but for now it seems to be working for me.